# Find n in arithmetic sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can solve for n if n∈ℕ: 
$$
(4+8+12 +  \ldots +4(n−1)) + (2+4.5+7 + \ldots +(4+5n)/2) = 126.5
$$
Thank you

Comment: When you write the sums like so:
$$
S= \sum_{k=2}^n \left(4 (k-1) \right) + \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{4+5k}{2}
$$
it's pretty easy to manipulate the expressions so that we can evaluate them. The goal is to isolate a term like
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k
$$

Comment: Couldn´t you use the hints of Matti P.?

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed with the hints of Matti. Would really like to know his way of solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:The first sum is:

$s_1=4(1+2+3+. . . n-1)=4\times\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2}=2n(n-1)$

The second sum $s_2$ is arithmetic progression $a=4.5$ and $d=2.5$ . We have:

$s_1+2+s_2=126.5$ ⇒ $s_1+s_2=124.5=3\times 41.5$

Let number of terms of $s_1$ be n and number of terms of $s_2$ be k, we can write:

$2n(n+1)+\frac{k}{2}[2\times 4.5 +(k-1)2.5]=3\times 41.5$

This relation deduces that  n and k must be divisible by 3. Now we have to check multiples of 3 for n and k such as (n, k)=(3,3), (6,3), (3, 6) (6, 6) . . etc. We find that $n=k=6 $ is the correct answer, because:

$s_1=2\times 6(6-1)=60$

$s_2=3[2\times 4.5+(6-1)2.5]=64.5$

⇒ $s_1 + s_2=60+64.5=124.5$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your hint? Thanks.

Comment: @LisaLevi, sorry for delay , I was out and could not reply. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Sirous for the detailed explanation. One last question I have is if n=k=6 can be found by trial and error or how do I know that 6 is the correct answer?

Comment: @LisaLevi, f(n)=2n^2-2n=60 and g(n)=\frac{n}{2}96.5+2.5 n)=64.5 have common solution which is 6, then the sum of two functions  becomes 142.5 which is entirely different to the roots of quadratic equation resulted from the sum of two functions. I choose k for the number of terms of second sum because I was not sure that n=k, so I had to check all options by try and error. I do not know any other method, if there is any.

Comment: Thank you so much again Sirous!

Comment: @LisaLevi, Your welcome.